# How can I get id of update request in request file?

Tags: laravel

How can I get id of update request in request file app/Http/Requests/UpdatePointRequest.php, where I have :

```
class UpdatePointRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        \Log::info( '-0 UpdatePointRequest $this->request::' . print_r( $this->request, true  ) );
        $request = request();
        \Log::info( '-1 UpdatePointRequest $request->all()::' . print_r( $request->all(), true  ) );

        // None of above have "id" field

        $validationRulesArray = [
            'title' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'max:255',
                Rule::unique($pointTable)->ignore($pointId),  // I need "id" field here
            ],
            ...
        ];
        ...
```

In  in telescope under requests the only where I find valid id is "Path" with value :

```
/api/points/112
```

In controller I have method defined :

```
public function update(UpdatePointRequest $request, Point $point): JsonResponse
{


"laravel/framework": "^10.34.2",
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: public function update(UpdatePointRequest $request, Point $point): JsonResponse
{        dd($point->id) ;    //here it is id and $point refer model rec or you can dd($point) to check what you get in $point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `route()` [helper](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing) method

```
 $pointId = $this->route('point');
```

Comment: By your url I did not find `$this->route` - method. I mean where $this->route belongs to request class. By $this->route('point') returned model, not id.

Comment: that because of laravel service container injection, you can get the id of the model in that way